# Remove Currency Character from Currency String in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, asp.net, string, decimal

How can I remove the currency character from a currency string e.g. `20,000.00 €`?. I need only the numeric figure for further processing the data. I have tried with `decimal.TryParse(temp, NumberStyles.Any.Sanitize(), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out result)` but this gives `result` as false because in my case, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is `en-US` whereas `€` is not US currency. Instead of `€`, if I pass `$`, it works fine, i.e. the value of `result` is true. Also, if the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is `de`, the same `20,000.00 €` value works fine.

I don't want to hardcode the culture here because in my application, I have 2 cultures, `en-US` and `de`. Can someone please suggest what I can do?

Comment: Remove the €? Or remove all non-numeric characters (plus `,` and `.`) from the string first?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/215552/heretic-monkey only '€'. I need only the numeric figure.

Comment: Just `@HereticMonkey` or type `@` and press Tab. The dupe covers removing everything except `.`. Add `,` to the solutions if you need those.